# How to create db in MySQL with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I need to create a db in MySQL using SQLAlchemy, I am able to connect to a db if it already exists, but I want to be able to create it if it does not exist. These are my tables:

```
    #def __init__(self):
Base = declarative_base()

class utente(Base):
    __tablename__="utente"
    utente_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    nome_utente=Column(Unicode(20))
    ruolo=Column(String(10))
    MetaData.create_all()

    def __repr(self):
        return "utente: {0}, {1}, id: {2}".format(self.ruolo,self.nome_utente,self.utente_id)
    
    
class dbmmas(Base):
    
    __tablename__="dbmmas"
    db_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    nome_db=Column(String(10))
    censimento=Column(Integer)
    versione=Column(Integer)
    ins_data=Column(DateTime)
    mod_data=Column(DateTime)
    ins_utente=Column(Integer)
    mod_utente=Column(Integer)
    MetaData.create_all()

    def __repr(self):
        return "dbmmas: {0}, censimento {1}, versione {2}".format(self.nome_db,self.censimento,self.versione)    
    
class funzione(Base):
    __tablename__="funzione"
    funzione_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    categoria=Column(String(10))
    nome=Column(String(20))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "funzione:{0},categoria:{1},id:{2} ".format(self.nome,self.categoria,self.funzione_id)
    
class profilo(Base):
    __tablename__="rel_utente_funzione" 
    utente_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    funzione_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    amministratore=Column(Integer)
    MetaData.create_all()
    
    def __repr(self):
        l=lambda x: "amministratore" if x==1 else "generico"
        return "profilo per utente_id:{0}, tipo: {1}, funzione_id: {2}".format(self.utente_id,l(self.amministratore),self.funzione_id)    
    
class aree(Base):
    __tablename__="rel_utente_zona"
    UTB_id=Column(String(10), primary_key=True) # "in realta' si tratta della seatureSignature della feature sullo shapefile"
    utente_id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    amministratore=Column(Integer)
    MetaData.create_all()
    def __repr(self):
        l=lambda x: "amministratore" if x==1 else "generico"
        return "zona: {0}, pe utente_id:{1}, {2}".format(self.UTB_id,self.utente_id,l(self.amministratore))
    
class rel_utente_dbmmas(Base):
    __tablename__="rel_utente_dbmmas"
    utente_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    db_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    amministratore=(Integer)
    MetaData.create_all()
    def __repr(self):
        l=lambda x: "amministratore" if x==1 else "generico"
        return "dbregistrato: {0} per l'utente{1} {2}".format(self.db_id,self.utente_id,l(self.amministratore))
```

Comment: Thanks, now i can create the db, is there a way to check the existence of the dbin advance? I can only think to use try

Answer (score 53):

To create a `mysql` database you just connect to the server an create the database:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://user:password@server') # connect to server
engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE dbname") #create db
engine.execute("USE dbname") # select new db
# use the new db
# continue with your work...
```

of course your user has to have the permission to create databases.

Comment: Don't forget the database API after the database server, using the format: "dialect+driver". For example, you could use "mysql+mysqldb".

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb

Comment: how is this get upvoted? you missing 1 import. @rmutalik was right. it gave me an error

Comment: It should work if you have the MySQLdb driver installed (as it is the default if none is specified), otherwise yes, you need to specify the driver you want to use in the connection string. No other import should be needed.

Comment: Downvote. Not explained what you need to `pip install` and that the start of the url depends on what you have installed.

Comment: These comments are a bit harsh: it's implicit in the original question that the asker already knows to connect, they just don't know how to create a database.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [SQLAlchemy-Utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for that.

`pip install sqlalchemy-utils`

Then you can do things like

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists
url = 'mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(user, pass, host, port)
if not database_exists(url):
    create_database(url)
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30971098/3846716), it helped me a lot.

Comment: while this answer  does require an additional package, i do like the simplicity and how modular it is. thanks!

Comment: you might want to specify encoding if you like to as follows: `create_database(url, encoding='utf8mb4')`

Answer (score 13):

I don't know what the canonical way is, but here's a way to check to see if a database exists by checking against the list of databases, and to create it if it doesn't exist.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# This engine just used to query for list of databases
mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(user, pass, host, port))

# Query for existing databases
existing_databases = mysql_engine.execute("SHOW DATABASES;")
# Results are a list of single item tuples, so unpack each tuple
existing_databases = [d[0] for d in existing_databases]

# Create database if not exists
if database not in existing_databases:
    mysql_engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE {0}".format(database))
    print("Created database {0}".format(database))

# Go ahead and use this engine
db_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(user, pass, host, port, db))
```

Here's an alternative method if you don't need to know if the database was created or not.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# This engine just used to query for list of databases
mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(user, pass, host, port))

# Query for existing databases
mysql_engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ".format(database))

# Go ahead and use this engine
db_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(user, pass, host, port, db))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Would recommend using `with`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

username = ''
password = ''
host = 'localhost'
port = 3306
DB_NAME = 'db_name'

engine = create_engine(f"mysql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}")

with engine.connect() as conn:
    # Do not substitute user-supplied database names here.
    conn.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {DB_NAME}")
```

Comment: Wrapping the SQL statement in `text` resolves "Not an executable object". 
```
from sqlalchemy import text
conn.execute(text(f"...."))
```

Answer (score 0):

The **mysqlclient** seems to be up to 10 times faster in benchmark tests than **PyMySQL**, see: [What's the difference between MySQLdb, mysqlclient and MySQL connector/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396881/11154841).

Yet, why not use a Python-ready package for Python, at least, if it is not about every second of query time? **PyMySQL** is suggested by the following links, for example:

- [Using SQLAlchemy to access MySQL without frustrating library installation issues](https://blog.rtwilson.com/using-sqlalchemy-to-access-mysql-without-frustrating-library-installation-issues/)
- [How to connect MySQL database using Python+SQLAlchemy remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355674/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-pythonsqlalchemy-remotely).

#### Python packages:

Install with pip, at best put in "requirements.txt":

- PyMySQL
- SQLAlchemy

*Again, if it is about the best speed of the query, use mysqlclient package. Then you need to install an additional Linux package with `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.*

#### `import` statements

Only one needed:

`import sqlalchemy`

#### Connection string (= db_url)

Connection string starting with [{dialect/DBAPI}](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html)+{driver}:

db_url = `mysql+pymysql://`

where `pymysql` stands for the used Python package "PyMySQL" as the driver.

*Again, if it is about the best speed of the query, use mysqlclient package. Then you need `mysql+msqldb://` at this point.*

For a remote connection, you need to add to the connection string:

- host
- user
- password
- database
- port (the port only if it is not the standard 3306)

You can create your db_url with several methods. Do not write user and password and at best any other variable value directly in the string to avoid possible attacks:

- [sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL), or with `.url.URL`, see an example at [Connecting from Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions) or an example which automatically adds `?` suffixes, for example `?driver=SQL+Server`, at the end of the string at [Building a connection URL for mssql+pyodbc with sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101255/11154841)
- `f"""...{my_var}..."""`
- `"""...{my_var}...""".format(my_var=xyz_var)`
- ...

Example without the url helper of SQLAlchemy:

```
db_url = "{dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}".format(
```

or:

```
db_url = "{dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}?host={host}?port={port}".format(
         dialect = 'mysql',
         driver = 'pymysql',
         username=db_user,
         password=db_pass,
         database=db_name,
         host=db_host,
         port=db_port
     )
```

#### Other engine configurations

For other connection drivers, dialects and methods, see the [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation - Engine Configuration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html)

#### Create the db if not exists

See [How to create a new database using SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506578/how-to-create-a-new-database-using-sqlalchemy).

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url)
if not sqlalchemy.database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute("commit")
    conn.execute("create database test")
```