# How to connect MySQL database using Python+SQLAlchemy remotely?

Tags: python, mysql, tcp, sqlalchemy, ssh-tunnel

I am having difficulty accessing MySQL remotely. I use SSH tunnel and want to connect the database MySQL using Python+SQLALchemy.

When i use MySQL-client in my console and specify "`ptotocol=TCP`", then everything is fine!
I use command:

```
mysql -h localhost —protocol=TCP -u USER -p
```

I get access to remote database through SSH-tunnel.

However, when I want to connect to the database using the Python+SQLAchemy I can't find such option like `—protocol=TCP`
Otherwise, i have only connect to local MySQL Databases.
Tell me please, is there a way to do it using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: set up an ssh tunnel, then point your local mysql at the tunnel port on the local machine. mysql won't know it's being tunneled, and ssh will take care of redirecting everything where it should go.

Comment: tunnel has already installed from X.X.X.X:3306 -> localhost:3306
Maybe i need to set tunnel to another port, for example localhost:3307?

Comment: @strevg In order to clarify things: you have a MySQL server running on your local host. And a second MySQL server accessed remotely through an SSH tunnel. Both are running simultaneously ? Which server is bound to which port on your local host ?

Comment: Both servers are running. Tunnel established between 3306 port of remote host - 3306 port of localhost(127.0.0.1). When i connected to localhost port 3306 with option —protocol=TCP i get all databases both remotely and local. Without using -protocol i obtain only list of local databases.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The classic answer to this issue is to use `127.0.0.1` or the *IP of the host* or the *host name* instead of the "special name" `localhost`. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html#idm140235558252992):

> [...] connections on Unix to *localhost* are made using a Unix socket file by default

And later:

> **On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name *localhost* specially**, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server.

---

However, this simple trick doesn't appear to work in your case, so you have to somehow *force* the use of a TCP socket. As you explained it yourself, when invoking `mysql` on the command line, you use the `--protocol tcp` option.

As explained [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-args), from SQLAlchemy, you can pass the relevant options (if any) to your driver either as URL options *or* using the `connect_args` keyword argument.

For example using *PyMySQL*, on a test system I've setup for that purpose (MariaDB 10.0.12, SQLAlchemy 0.9.8 and PyMySQL 0.6.2) I got the following results:

```
>>> engine = create_engine(
      "mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@localhost/db?host=localhost?port=3306")
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                               Force TCP socket. Notice the two uses of `?`
#                               Normally URL options should use `?` and `&`  
#                               after that. But that doesn't work here (bug?)
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn.execute("SELECT host FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()").fetchall()
[('localhost:54164',)]

# Same result by using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost: 
>>> engine = create_engine(
      "mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@127.0.0.1/db?host=localhost?port=3306")
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn.execute("SELECT host FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()").fetchall()
[('localhost:54164',)]

# Alternatively, using connect_args:
>>> engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@localhost/db",
                       connect_args= dict(host='localhost', port=3306))
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn.execute("SELECT host FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()").fetchall()
[('localhost:54353',)]
```

As you noticed, both will use a TCP connection (I know that because of the port number after the hostname). On the other hand:

```
>>> engine = create_engine(
      "mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@localhost/db?unix_socket=/path/to/mysql.sock")
#                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                               Specify the path to mysql.sock in
#                               the `unix_socket` option will force
#                               usage of a UNIX socket

>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn.execute("SELECT host FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()").fetchall()
[('localhost',)]

# Same result by using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost: 
>>> engine = create_engine(
      "mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@127.0.0.1/db?unix_socket=/path/to/mysql.sock")
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn.execute("SELECT host FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()").fetchall()
[('localhost',)]

# Alternatively, using connect_args:
>>> engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@localhost/db",
                       connect_args= dict(unix_socket="/path/to/mysql.sock"))
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> conn.execute("SELECT host FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID = CONNECTION_ID()").fetchall()
[('localhost',)]
```

No port after the *hostname*: this is an UNIX socket.

Comment: Nice. This also worked for me working with a local (non-root) mysql installation, where I had a non-standard `port` and `unix_socket` I needed to set.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQLdb appears to have gotten more strict. Now you get a TypeError, beacuse SQLAlchemy is passing in the port as a string and MySQLdb expects an int. :/

Comment: Thanks @sylvain
"# Alternatively, using connect_args:
>>> engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://sylvain:passwd@localhost/db",
                       connect_args= dict(host='localhost', port=3306))" 
worked for me

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>')    
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM <table_name>', cnx) #read the entire table
```

Where credentials are added to mysql database like this:

```
CREATE USER '<username>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<username>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: tiny addition, might also need the port. "mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>"

Comment: No import of pymysql needed when using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 11):

In my setup (I'm using mysql-python) just using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the MySQL SQLAlchemy url works. The complete url I'm using exactly for that scenario (tunnel with local port 3307) is:

```
mysql:/user:passwd@127.0.0.1:3307/
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.0.5, but I guess that doesn't matter too much...

Comment: Indeed, 127.0.0.1 is localhost, @BK435, but it doesn't work with localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. This seems to be due to how musql deals with "localhost", insisting in connecting via filesystem sockets instead of TCP sockets. That's why the option --protocol=tcp for mysql is mentioned in the question. But it seems that 127.0.0.1 does the trick, and is simpler than the current answer.

Answer (score 3):

I Tried this to connect with mysql db of xampp server

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://usrnme:passwd@hstnme/dbname")
```

Comment: where do we put the port number, if the MySQL DB is dockerised and exposed on a different one than 3306?

Comment: You can pass the port number with 'hstnme' using ':' separation. e.g. 'hstnme:3306'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.x you can use:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Then:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
engine = db.create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@hostname:port/dbname")
```

Comment: This question is about how the host is specified; which connector is used is not really relevant.