# How to Make SQLAlchamey Web Proxy Aware?

Tags: python, proxy, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy for a project at work where my app sits behind a firewall. Able to use SQLAlchemy for internal connections all day long, but when I want to connect to an outside database, I am unable to. Searching for 'proxy' on the documentation returns articles around creating a read/write view of a target attribute.

When using the Requests python library, I make it web proxy aware by passing the HTTP proxy links into the connection.

Suggestions? Are we able to make SQLAlchemy webproxy aware?

Comment: [This question and it's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355674/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-pythonsqlalchemy-remotely) seem related to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Silly me. For some reason I thought that SQLAlchemy was using HTTP not TCP/IP connection, which is blocked by my firewall.