# What's the difference between MySQLdb, mysqlclient and MySQL connector/Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python, mysql-connector

So I've been trying to do some database update with python and while setting up the whole dev environment, I came across these three things which made me dizzy.

1. There's [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)
2. There's [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient)
3. And then there's a [mysql connector python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/)

What's each of them, the difference and where to use them? Thanks

Comment: Most languages have several database adapter layers of varying levels of sophistication, support and quality.

Comment: mysqlclient is a forked version of MySQLdb with python3.3+ support, and mysql connector is official module from mysql.

Comment: We have also pymysql

Comment: From all these answers, it's still not really clear what exactly MySQLdb, mysqlclient, and "mysql connector python" are, and what the relationship is between each of them, if any. You can kind of piece it together from multiple answers. (The best answer would also describe MySQLdb1, PyMySQL, and, to help people like me, aiomysql. Describe what each is, and what the relationships are.)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

[MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) is a thin python wrapper around C module which implements API for MySQL database.

There was [MySQLDb1](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1) version of wrapper used some time ago and now it is considered to be a legacy. As MySQLDb1 started evolving to [MySQLDb2](https://github.com/farcepest/moist) with bug fixes and Python3 support, a MySQLDb1 was forked and here is how [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) appeared, with bugfixes and Python3 support. Sum up, so now we have MySQLDb2 which is not ready for production use, MySQLDb1 as an outdated driver and a community supported mysqlclient with bug fixes and Python3 support.

Now, to solve that mess, MySQL provides their own version of MySQL adapter - [mysql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-introduction.html), an all-in python module that uses MySQL API with ***no C modules dependencies*** and only standard python modules used.

So now the question comes down to: mysqlclient vs mysql connector.

As for me, I would go with officially supported library, however `mysqlclient` should be a good choice as well.
Both of them are being actively updated with fixes and new features which you can see by active commits in last days.

*Note: I did not have much experience with them, so there might be cases when one or another does not suite your needs. Both libraries follow [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) standard which means you should be fine with at least base functionality everywhere.*

**Installation and Dependencies**

- mysqlclient

As a fork of C wrapper it requires C modules to work with MySQL which adds python header files to build these extensions (read python-dev). Installation depends on the system you use, just make sure you aware of package names and can install them.

- mysql connector
  [Main documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html) is pretty clear, however you should be aware of [Protobuf C++](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads) dependency (for mysql connector [versions >= 2.2.3](https://github.com/sanpingz/mysql-connector)).

Comment: The Protofbuf dependency is not for the regular Connector/Python module, it's for the X DevAPI version, which is distributed separately under the name `mysqlx-connector-python`. Regular Connector/Python is written purely in Python [with only standard library dependencies](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-introduction.html).

Answer (score 119):

There are thee MySQL adapters for Python that are currently maintained:

- [`mysqlclient`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) - By far the fastest MySQL connector for CPython. Requires the `mysql-connector-c` C library to work.
- [`PyMySQL`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) - Pure Python MySQL client. [According to the maintainer of both `mysqlclient` and `PyMySQL`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/342#issuecomment-104939515), you should use `PyMySQL` if:

  - You can't use `libmysqlclient` for some reason.
  - You want to use monkeypatched socket of gevent or eventlet.
  - You wan't to hack mysql protocol.
- [`mysql-connector-python`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python) - MySQL connector developed by the MySQL group at Oracle, also written entirely in Python. It's performance appears to be the worst out of the three. Also, due to some licensing issues, you can't download it from PyPI (but it's now available through conda).

#### Benchmarks

According to the following benchmarks, `mysqlclient` is faster (sometimes > 10x faster) than the pure Python clients.

- [Benchmarking MySQL drivers (Python 3.4)](https://gist.github.com/methane/90ec97dda7fa9c7c4ef1)
- [PyMySQL Evaluation](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/PyMySQL_evaluation)
- [Python MySQLdb vs mysql-connector query performance](http://charlesnagy.info/it/python/python-mysqldb-vs-mysql-connector-query-performance)

Comment: So looks like `PyMySQL` is still the way to go if using PyPy.

Comment: in case you have problems with compiling mysqlclient you may install it via wheel package as described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077052/2848256

Comment: does sqlalchemy support mysqlclient ?

Comment: @vishal AFAIK `mysqlclient` is the default connector used by sqlalchemy when your database URL starts with `mysql://...`. To use `PyMySQL`, start your URL with `mysql+pymysql://...`. To use `mysql-connector-python`, start your URL with `mysql+mysqlconnector://...`. See [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb) for more info.

Comment: FYI, the official package `mysql-connector-python` can also utilize C extension: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext.html

Comment: `mysql-connector-python` has been up on PyPi for [quite a while](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/#history).

Answer (score 30):

> A lot of options provided by users. Little late to party. But my **2
>   cents** in on with benchmarking for pypy 3.7 version.

### Stick to mysqlclient if you want faster access and repetitive access

```
MySQL Connector/Python: 23.096168518066406 [sec]
mysqlclient: 6.815327882766724 [sec]
PyMySQL: 24.616853952407837 [sec]
MySQL Connector/Python: 22.619106769561768 [sec]
mysqlclient: 6.607790231704712 [sec]
PyMySQL: 24.410773038864136 [sec]
```

Loop... from previous benchmarking...

```
def q100k(cur):
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(100000):
        cur.execute("SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6")
        res = cur.fetchall()
        assert len(res) == 1
        assert res[0] == (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    return time.time() - t
```

Answer (score 4):

**For developers using SQLAlchemy**

This question was a good starting point for learning what DBAPIs are available for Python and their tradeoffs. However, the libraries mentioned above are ever-changing, and their performance and issues are not set in stone. Hence, testing the individual dialects and evaluating their performance for yourself would be a good approach.

I have provided below links listing the available DBAPIs. Those links include references to each library's documentation and a commentary on their features and support.

- For MariaDB: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.base
- PostgreSQL: [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#:~:text=DBAPI%20Support-,%C2%B6,-The%20following%20dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#:%7E:text=DBAPI%20Support-,%C2%B6,-The%20following%20dialect)
- More Database dialects can be found in the side menu [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#mysql).

To understand what DBAPIs are in general, use this [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/glossary.html#term-DBAPI), as well as reading the above mentioned [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). In addition, the diagram below can help you visualise where DBAPIs belong [architecturally](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html).
[image]

Answer (score -2):

(I haven't done my own testing to verify all of the information below, but I've used mysqlclient for years, and I researched carefully.)

## MySQLdb, mysqlclient, and PyMySQL

MySQLdb, mysqlclient, and PyMySQL are packages that provide a similar API.

If you install the MySQLdb package or the mysqlclient package with pip, then a `MySQLdb` module will be installed (for example `venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/`). So whether you install the MySQLdb package or the mysqlclient package, you use it by importing `MySQLdb`: `import MySQLdb`.

If you install PyMySQL with pip, then a MySQLdb module will **not** be installed. But PyMySQL includes an `install_as_MySQLdb` function that can be used to define a `MySQLdb` module in memory at runtime, that actually references PyMySQL.

So there are a few ways you can use PyMySQL:

1. `import pymysql` and use `pymysql` like you would `MySQLdb`, since it has the same API.
2. Call `install_as_MySQLdb` and then use `import MySQLdb`. (This is probably useful if a dependency imports `MySQLdb`.)
3. `import pymysql as MySQLdb`.

## MySQL Connector/Python

My impression is that "MySQL Connector/Python" provides a different API.

## Django note

Django's ORM [can be used with either](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) of the 2 APIs. That is, it can be used with the MySQLdb/mysqlclient/PyMySQL API, or the "MySQL Connector/Python" API.