# Import error when using django with WSGI

Tags: mysql, django, apache, anaconda, mod-wsgi

I am working on a little hobby project which I want to publish under an open source license. I use the django framework 2.0 and I am now testing my application on the Apache web server. I use Anaconda3 to manage the virtual environment for the project. I already tested my application with SQLite as db backend, but if I use MySQL instead, the web server log says that mysqlclient can't import _mysql. I tried to run the dj development server on the python vm and it is working. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `mysqlclient`, use [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL). And in wsgi.py use this at top:

```
#wsgi.py
import os

...
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Reason for using `pymysql` is: [What's the difference between MySQLdb, mysqlclient and MySQL connector/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396881/2696165)