# How to install mysqlclient in python?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to Python, coming from Java and JS background,
I've installed Python and Pip in my local machine,
I am trying to learn Django, using MySQL,
But I am unable to install the `mysqlclient` using pip,
**I used the following command to do so -**

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

**It's giving the following error -**

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ms/q8s67d8n09q59mbpshz3dq9m0000gn/T/pip-install-nk55db_s/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ms/q8s67d8n09q59mbpshz3dq9m0000gn/T/pip-install-nk55db_s/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/ms/q8s67d8n09q59mbpshz3dq9m0000gn/T/pip-install-nk55db_s/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/ms/q8s67d8n09q59mbpshz3dq9m0000gn/T/pip-install-nk55db_s/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/ms/q8s67d8n09q59mbpshz3dq9m0000gn/T/pip-install-nk55db_s/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/private/var/folders/ms/q8s67d8n09q59mbpshz3dq9m0000gn/T/pip-install-nk55db_s/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**Screenshot -**

[image]

Comment: Try,`pip install pymysql`. https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/

Comment: Hi, It seems it got installed, but then what's the difference between `mysqlclient` and `pymysql`? Will it cause config issues later on?

Comment: `pymysql` is a pure python MySQL client whereas `mysqlclient` requires `mysql-connector-c`. If you like to read me check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396881/3091398).

Comment: so no code changes right? I can use MySql as usual? The only difference here was, we used different client yea?

Comment: No much difference, you can use it as usual.

Answer (score 3):

`mysqlclient` requires additional `c` libraires.
For linux (Debian):
`$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`
For Mac:
`$ brew install mysql`
Further reading at the [home page](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Answer (score 2):

I am solve error following process

```
Python 3.8.0
```

First install in Homebraw type following command. type this command in terminal

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

```
brew install mariadb-connector-c

pip install mysqlclient
```

more issues follow this tutorial
https://medium.com/@MrWeeble/homebrew-on-mac-and-pythons-mysqlclient-ea44fa300e70

Comment: Worked on `Python 3.8.2` and `macOS Big Sur (M1)`