# Building a connection URL for mssql+pyodbc with sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, connection-string, pyodbc

## The problem...

I am trying to connect to a MSSql server via SQLAlchemy.  Here is my code with fake credentials (*not my real credentials obviously*).

## The code...

```
credentials = {
'username'  : 'SPOTTER_xyz_ACC',
'password'  : '123Goodbye2016!@#',
'host'      : 'MARYLQLT01',
'database'  : 'LRS_DUS',
'port'      : '1560'}

connect_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    'mssql+pyodbc',
    username=credentials['username'],
    password=credentials['password'],
    host=credentials['host'],
    port=credentials['port'],
    query=dict(service_name=credentials['database']))

engine = create_engine(connect_url)
connection=engine.connect()
```

And this is the .pyodbc error that I am getting.

```
(pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

## Additional Details

But, here is what is weird... I if make a pyodbc connection and use Pandas.read_sql, then I can get data without an error.  So I do not understand why I am getting a 'pyodbc' error????

```
connection=pyodbc.connect(\
                          'Driver={SQL Server}; \
                          Server=MARYLQLT01; \
                          Database=LRS_DUS; \
                          UID=SPOTTER_xyz_ACC; \
                          PWD=123Goodbye2016!@#')

stmt='select * from PD_SC_All'
df=pd.read_sql(stmt,connection)
```

And then I can see the dataframe.

So, why am I getting the `(pyodbc.Error)` when I try to connect with SQLAlchemy?

### System Information

```
Windows 7
SQLAlchemy: 1.1.11
pyodbc: 4.0.16

Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Comment: Your connection URL is missing the ODBC driver name. You need something like `mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@myhost:port/databasename?driver=SQL+Server` (ref: [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc)).

Comment: This is still not working.  the `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL()` does not have a place to put `driver = SQL+Server'`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As stated in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc), for `mssql+pyodbc` connections

> When using a hostname connection, the driver name must also be specified in the query parameters of the URL.
>
> ```
> engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@myhost:port/databasename?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")
> ```

For

```python
credentials = {
    'username': 'scott',
    'password': 'tiger',
    'host': 'myhost',
    'database': 'databasename',
    'port': '1560'}
```

your statement produces the `connect_url`

```
mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@myhost:1560?service_name=databasename
```

What you really need is

```python
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connect_url = URL.create(
    'mssql+pyodbc',
    username=credentials['username'],
    password=credentials['password'],
    host=credentials['host'],
    port=credentials['port'],
    database=credentials['database'],
    query=dict(driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'))
```

which produces

```
mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@myhost:1560/databasename?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```

Comment: Since version 1.4.17 sqlalchemy requires a `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL` to create the engine, we can't use just a string anymore (which was my case) this answer save me after 2 days searching about that.

Comment: Well, this is a headache...
Can't get it to work, I'll start considering a career change for a java developer soon if this goes on.

Comment: Finally, using sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create() did the job.