# SQL Alchemy with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2014

I wasn't sure what to title my post, if you have a better idea, feel free to edit the title.

I have not used SQL Alchemy before and the documentation that I have looked at located in the following places, is not helpful:

- [Connecting to SQL Database Using SQL Alchemy in Python](https://medium.com/@anushkamehra16/connecting-to-sql-database-using-sqlalchemy-in-python-2be2cf883f85)
- [Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_core_connecting_to_database.htm)

Here is the code I am using:

```
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#Here are the parameters I am using:

 - server = 'Q-20/fake_example'
 - database = 'AdventureWorks2017'
 - driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' 
 - trusted_connection='yes'

DATABASE_CONNECTION = 'mssql+pyodbc://@server = ' + server + '/database = ' + database + '?trusted_connection = ' + trusted_connection + '&driver=' + driver

engine = sal.create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION)
```

All of that seems to work fine without any problems; however, when I add this line:

```
connection=engine.connect()
```

I get the following error message:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001',
>   '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes
>   Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53)
>   (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   (53)')

I am not sure what is wrong with what I am doing, does anyone have any suggestions?

**What I have tried so far:**

1. I have confirmed that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. I did this check by following the instructions [here](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)
2. Removing the "@" sign before the server, but this just generated the same error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085451/building-a-connection-url-for-mssqlpyodbc-with-sqlalchemy-engine-url-url

Comment: Thank you, helped a little bit, but I still have errors.

Comment: Do the [Hostname Connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections) and [Pass through exact Pyodbc string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string) sections provide any help?

Comment: I edited my post after playing around with it. Progress, but still stuck. I'll take a look though.

Comment: You don't need the `@` symbol before the server name if you're using a trusted connection

Comment: I got the same error message.

Comment: I was using the wrong driver and instance name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out part of what I needed to do. I needed to change my parameters.

**Old Parameters:**

- server = 'Q-20/fake_example'
- database = 'AdventureWorks2017'
- driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
- trusted_connection='yes'

**New Parameters:**

- server = 'Q-20'
- database = 'AdventureWorks2017'
- driver = 'SQL+SERVER+NATIVE+CLIENT+11.0'
- trusted_connection='yes'

This is what my code ultimately looked like:

```
database_connection =  'mssql+pyodbc://Q-20/AdventureWorks2017?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+SERVER+NATIVE+CLIENT+11.0'
```