# sqlalchemy confuses the parameters when trying to connect to a db

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MS SQL server using sqlalchemy and pyodbc and am following all the steps from their own tutorial but it fails. When I debug it, I see that the parameters sent to sqlalchemy are messed up. For example host is username, password is port and so on.

What I am trying to connect to is:

```
Host = 'host_address123'
Port = 7003
Username = 'user'
Password = 'pass'
DB = 'db-main'
```

I use the following command:

```
url = 'mssql+pyodc://Username:Password@Host,port?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'
engine = sal.create_engine(url)
```

When I try to test a simple query it fails and says creds are wrong or network issues. I know that creds are correct. Can someone help. I'm not married to sqlalchemy and use any other package as long as it works. I keep seeing all the post make it seem very easy but honestly I have been struglling for a long time.

Thanks

Comment: `Host,port` shouldn't that be `Host:port`?

Comment: I expect the issues are multitude. What's `pyodc` for example? If you're uncomfortable constructing URLs can I suggest that you consider [`URL.create()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#creating-urls-programmatically) as provided by SQLAlchemy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101255/2144390