# how to search for the existence of a database with sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to write a script with python sqlalchemy that searchs if a database exist, if the database exists it should query the database else create database and tables.

Pseudocode:

```
   if db exists cursor.execute(sql)
   else
      create db test;
      create tables;
      insert data;
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.connect()` method, which will raise a `OperationalError` if the database does not exist.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sqla
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
db = sqla.create_engine(database_uri)
try:
    db.connect()
    db.execute(sql)
except OperationalError:
    # Switch database component of the uri
    default_database_uri = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
                           str(db.engine.url)), 'mysql')
    db = sqla.create_engine(default_database_uri)
    # Create your missing database/tables/data here
    # ...
```

Comment: connect() doesn't raise an exception, instead it just creates and empty one

Answer (score 26):

An alternate way if you don't mind to import other libs is to use sqlalchemy_utils. Then `database_exists` does what you expect, which you may pass the sqlalchemy database uri.

```
if database_exists('sqllite:////tmp/test.db'):
    do_stuff_with_db(db)
```

http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database_helpers.html

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work in Python 3.8 yet

Comment: It works for me with Python 3.8, but _not_ if the SQLite DB lives somwhere under `/tmp`

Answer (score 4):

Create an engine that connects to the database and executes a universal query like `SELECT 1;`. If it fails, you can create the DB. How to create the new database depends on the DBMS though.

With PostgreSQL you would connect to the `postgres` database and issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement, then connect to the newly created database.

Comment: i have a pool of database already in existance so if i create a universal query it will pick those and not create the one i want. I was hoping that there is an sqlalchemy equivalent to mysql if not exist create database query.

Comment: By "universal" I mean it works on all SQL databases - I don't know which backend(s) you're using. `create_engine(my_target_dsn).execute('select 1')` won't interfere with your existing pool.

Comment: my bad i get you i thought of that but it seemed so plain and easy i didnt think it would work. by the way im using python and sqlalchemy

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what the canonical way is but here's a way to check to see if a database exists by checking against the list of databases.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# This engine just used to query for list of databases
mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(user, pass, host, port))

# Query for existing databases
existing_databases = mysql_engine.execute("SHOW DATABASES;")
# Results are a list of single item tuples, so unpack each tuple
existing_databases = [d[0] for d in existing_databases]

# Create database if not exists
if database not in existing_databases:
    mysql_engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE {0}".format(database))
    print("Created database {0}".format(database))

# Go ahead and use this engine
db_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(user, pass, host, port, db))
```

Here's an alternative method if you don't need to know if the database was created or not.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# This engine just used to query for list of databases
mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(user, pass, host, port))

# Query for existing databases
mysql_engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ".format(database))

# Go ahead and use this engine
db_engine = create_engine('mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(user, pass, host, port, db))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
There's a helper called [database_exists()](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database_helpers.html#database-exists)

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide to go with sqlalchemy_utils, make sure that you apply your connect_args as a querystring. Otherwise those args won't be carried over when the `database_exists` function [recreates the sqlalchemy engine](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/blob/d4f9fb0ce98be47e2d2fd2c1d21e30b0174ab7d5/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.py#L470)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists

connect_args = {'charset': 'utf8'}
connect_args['ssl_cert'] = 'certs/client-cert.pem'
connect_args['ssl_key'] = 'certs/client-key.pem'
connect_args['ssl_ca'] = 'certs/server-ca.pem'

engine = create_engine(os.environ['MYSQL_CONN_URL'] + '/' + os.environ['DB_NAME'] + '?' +  urlencode(connect_args))
print(database_exists(engine.url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the pip package

```
pip install sqlalchemy_utils
```

Check with database_exists

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost/name')
database_exists(engine.url)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just check with the default `import os` if the file exists.

```
import os
database_uri = "C:\\"
name_of_db = "Random.db"
db_exists = os.path.isfile(database_uri + name_of_db)
```

Comment: This will work for databases that are implemented as single files (SQLIte, MS Access?), but not for servers like MySQL etc.