# sqlalchemy connect to server, with not specify database

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc

Is it possible to connect to **MSSQL server**, using **sqlalchemy** and thencreate a database?

I use the following:

`sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sa:pwd@localhost/")`

But I get an error:

`Detail DBAPIError: (Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') None None`

I would like to connect to the server, then create database and work with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
import urllib

connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;UID=sa;PWD=pwd"
connection_string = urllib.quote_plus(connection_string) 
connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % connection_string

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute("create database test")
connection.close()
```

Part of the code was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977109/771848).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It not connects to server, I've already wrote it, sorry, maybe I've not correctly described my problem. I get the same error.

Comment: How about using this as a connection string `mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER%3D{SQL Server}%3BSERVER%3Dlocalhost%3BUID%3Dsa%3BPWD%3Dpwd`?

Comment: The idea is to make `pyodbc` connection string without `Database` setting, take a look: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#additional-connection-examples

Comment: Thanks, now it connects to db server, but not log in to it. I think what problems are in my password, because it contain special chars, such as '&'. How can I use this characters in this string?

Comment: It is works fine, thank you very much. Also please fix next string for other people in your example: `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sa:pwd@localhost")`
should be `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)` and 
`connection.execute("commit")` not needed in this case

Comment: I think this only works if there is a database under the username you're connecting with

Comment: quote_plus is now included in parse.
Use `urllib.parse.quote_plus()`