# Data source name not found and no default driver error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

This is the code that I have

```
import time
import urllib
import openpyxl
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, text, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from astropy.table.tests.test_index import engine
from _sqlite3 import connect


connection_string = "DRIVER = {SQL Server};DATABASE =<dbname>; SERVER=<details>; UID =uid; PWD =pwd"
connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" %connection_string

#engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://UID:PWD@Servername:1433/DBname')

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

Base = declarative_base()

class Blc(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'BLC_Database'

    Row_no = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = Column(String)
    RES = Column(String)
    BTTLCOLUMN = Column(String)
    CS_HR = Column(Float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<BLC_Databse(Row_no = '%d', date='%s', RES = '%s', BTTLCOLUMN = '%s', CS_HR = '%0.2f')>" %(self.Row_no, self.date, self.RES, self.BTTLCOLUMN, self.CS_HR)    

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

print('Connection Successful')
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am trying to connect to a SQL server. I tried different string options. I visited this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941050/sqlalchemy-connect-to-server-with-not-specify-database) too. I am not able to understand the error.

Comment: Doesn't your DSN need a database name?  You have server, username, and password, but no database name...

Comment: @larks sorry I missed that! I have edited the code. If you notice the other method I tried which is commented, it has the database name. I used the same parameters in both statements. Still does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

I went to ODBC administration and created a new DSN and used that to connect.

```
create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://UID:PWD@DSN')
```

You dont need to mention the driver. You can assign a default database while configuring your DSN if you have multiple databases in one server. This worked for me.