# Is it possible to connect to a postgres server with SQLAlchemy without specifying a database?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to automatically create a test database before running my tests without shelling out, but I'm struggling to connect to the postgres server without connecting to a database.

If I give `create_engine()` a `URL` with `.database` `None` it tries to connect to a default database name.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

I was going a long the lines of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784334/311220

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the postgres without specyfing db using psql? As you can see it will always connect to default. So what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to connect to the default `postgres` database which should always be present. Then once connected you can create the desired databases.