# how to connect to postgresql with python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to create a `postgresql` database via sqlalchemy in pycharm (running python 3.6) but have trouble connecting / creating the database.

I initially started with `sqlalchemy` tutorial:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_table


engine =create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/test")
connection = engine.connect()
connection.close()
```

But it print's the error: `could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

How should I be opening up the port, or pointing it to the localhost?

Is there any specific thing that I need to do to create the database before i run `create_engine`?

I've also been searching online and found that perhaps I should be using `psycopg2` to create the database, but I don't understand how this is to be done.

What I would like is to create a `postgresql` database on my desktop, in a specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the `psycopg2` connector installed, then all you need to specify in the the connection string is `postgresql`, so your connection string would be something like

`postgresql://tim:xyzzy@somehost/somedb`

By default, PostgreSQL only listens on the `localhost` IP address, 127.0.0.1. So if the PostgreSQL server is on a different system you will need to configure the listen address in `postgresql.conf`

You will also need to have created the database before attempting to connect to it with SQLAlchemy. So you need to so a `createdb` when logged in as the PostgreSQL user.

```
tim@merlin:~$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@merlin:~$ createdb foo
postgres@merlin:~$
```

Comment: Hmm, how do I create a postgres database in windows?

Comment: If PostgreSQL is already on your Windows there should be a tool called pgAdmin. Try running that and creating a database.

Comment: So unlike `sqlite`, which can create the database through `sqlalchemy`, `postgresql database` cannot be created through `sqlalchemy` and can only be created through `pgAdmin`?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. You could connect as the postgres user and issue a CREATE DATABASE statement, although this seems like more work than simply using pgAdmin. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506578/how-to-create-a-new-database-using-sqlalchemy for more details.