# Can a path be specified to create a database using postgresql on sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to create a postgresql database using sqlalchemy and would like this database file to be created in an external hard drive. I can do that using sqlite3 which can be done just be adding the path after the string that will go into the engine:

```
# To create the tables we need these packages
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 

# Creating the base.
Base = declarative_base()

# The tables would be defined here.

# Create an engine that stores data in the given directory.
path = '/path/'
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+path+'ARsdb.db')    

# Create all tables in the engine.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Which will then make the database file within the specified path. On the other hand postgresql uses a different syntax for the engine:

```
# default
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost/mydatabase')

# psycopg2
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@localhost/mydatabase')
```

as explained on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506578/how-to-create-a-new-database-using-sqlalchemy) or the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html). However it is not clear for me if I can specify a path for this database file to be written like on the sqlite. When I created the database using the database string as:

```
postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/databasepath/database_name
```

for a mock database I couldn't find the **database_name** file inside the **databasepath** path. Can I specify a path for the file to be created after all or they stay confined within the server created during postgresql installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Postgres stores the data for **all** databases of a [cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) (aka "instance") inside a [single directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html) which is specified during the creation of the Postgres instance (via [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html)).

Additionally, you can't create a database by connecting to it. You need to first run the [`create database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) command, only then you can connect to it.